# Eliminating visitor pattern in C#

Tags: c#

I have code that looks like this:

```
var visitor = new ImplementsVisitor();
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
    arrray[i].Accept(visitor);
```

Each element in the array implements `IItem` interface, which has an `Accept(IVisitor)` method. Nothing but the standard visitor pattern.

While measuring performance, I came to the conclusion that the call by interface is too slow, and in this code is performance is critical. From your experience, what would be the best option of eliminating any virtual or interface calls? An if statement that checks for the concrete type? An enum on each element with a switch/case (in this case, the code's structure is such that no cast will be required)? Something else?

P.S. I cannot sort the items in the array. The order is important. Thus, I cannot sort them by concrete type to help branch prediction.

Comment: "I came to the conclusion that the call by interface is too slow" I'm sorry, I don't believe this. Could you show a typical implementation of `Accept` in any of `IItem`'s implementations?

Comment: could you use asynchronous programming?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I can, but it will be meaningless without context. The context is too long for a post on SO. What I can tell you is that it performs a small number (5-10) mathematical operations which include basic arithmetic, Math.Pow, Math.Exp and Math.Log.

About not believing - please do believe. The same operations manually coded (for a specifc instance of `array`) are 10x faster.

Comment: @BOR4 The operation inside `Accept` is too short for this. Asynchrony will be a huge overhead!

Comment: @Alex it is kinda hard to answer performance questions when we don't have complete code =)

Comment: @Alex Five calls to `Math.Pow` will easily outdo a single interface-based dispatch overhead (i.e. the difference between invoking through an interface vs. invoking directly) at a 10:1 ratio. Make a simple experiment: construct an array of items of the same type, and try your current implementation vs. an implementation that uses the exact subtype for `arr`, and see if you can measure the difference. I am betting that the answer would be "no".

Comment: I agree to @dasblinkenlight, but I do wonder what the manually coded code looks like to be 10x faster.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a cross-thread call here? That would explain the slowness. Otherwise merely making a virtual (indirect) call is generally a trivial cost, certainly less than a type check. (I say trivial because in a loop the vtable will usually be in the L3 cache)

Answer (score 3):

I created the following program. On my laptop the loop runs a million times in 8ms (that's a Release build, Debug is 11ms or so). That is approximately 0.000008ms to do the virtual dispatch and increment an int. Exactly how fast do you need it to be? I'd suspect that something has gone wrong with either your performance test or mine. If mine I'd be interested to hear suggestions for improvement.

Generally if performance at this level isn't good enough then using C# is probably a problem in itself. Its garbage collector has a habit of freezing threads in the middle of loops for example. If 0.000008ms on a loop iteration really is an issue, I'd suspect Assembly language or C would be a better choice.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int count = 1000000;

            IList<IItem> items = new List<IItem>(count);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var rnd = new Random();
                if (rnd.NextDouble() > 0.5)
                {
                    items.Add(new ClassA());
                }
                else
                {
                    items.Add(new ClassB());
                }
            }

            var visitor = new MyVisitor();

            Stopwatch s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
            {
                items[i].Accept(visitor);
            }
            s.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("ExecTime = {0}, Per Cycle = {1}", s.ElapsedMilliseconds, (double)s.ElapsedMilliseconds / count);
            visitor.Output();
        }

        interface IVisitor
        {
            void Process(ClassA item);
            void Process(ClassB item);
        }

        interface IItem
        {
            void Accept(IVisitor visitor);
        }

        abstract class BaseVisitor : IVisitor
        {
            public virtual void Process(ClassA item)
            {

            }

            public virtual void Process(ClassB item)
            {

            }
        }

        class ClassA : IItem
        {
            public void Accept(IVisitor visitor)
            {
                visitor.Process(this);
            }
        }

        class ClassB : IItem
        {
            public void Accept(IVisitor visitor)
            {
                visitor.Process(this);
            }
        }

        class MyVisitor : BaseVisitor
        {
            int a = 0;
            int b = 0;

            public override void Process(ClassA item)
            {
                a++;
            }

            public override void Process(ClassB item)
            {
                b++;
            }

            public void Output()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("a = {0}, b = {1}", a, b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have one virtual call here, you have two, but you only need one. First your array presumably has a virtual call through IItem - but if these are all the same type, and you know the type (and it is sealed) a virtual call is unnecessary.

Then within the visited object, you need to do whatever operation the visitor wants to do. This will probably also involve a virtual call.

You might do better with a typed IVisitor:

```
 interface IItem<TVisitor> : IItem 
     where TVisitor : IVisitor
 {
     void Accept(TVisitor visitor);
 }

 // Then
 SpecialVisitor visitor = ImplementsSpecialVisitor();
 foreach(var item in arrayOfSpecialItems){
     item.Accept<SpecialVisitor>(visitor);
 }
```